# Android google now cards text color code

Tags: android, google-now

What is the color code for the gray color used in this image of google now cards?[image]

Also, which font is used for the small and large text?(heading and subheading of each card)
Thanks

Comment: purpose? faking it? >:|

Comment: yes in a way. I am trying to implement the same layout :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**#878787** is the darkest, and;

**#DEDEDE** is the lightest.

Thank you, Instant Eyedropper!
Font: Roboto Light

Comment: and what about the font which is used? is it roboto light?

Comment: @ShivamBhalla It is Roboto, and light I believe.